# Unnecessary escape character: \` no-useless-escape

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, eslint

I am using thing url regex validation and also have eslint integrated in project.

```
let url = /^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$/
```

But when I compile my code getting below errors

```
  4:49  error  Unnecessary escape character: \`  no-useless-escape
  4:62  error  Unnecessary escape character: \.  no-useless-escape
  4:75  error  Unnecessary escape character: \$  no-useless-escape
  4:79  error  Unnecessary escape character: \(  no-useless-escape
  4:81  error  Unnecessary escape character: \)  no-useless-escape
  4:83  error  Unnecessary escape character: \*  no-useless-escape
  4:85  error  Unnecessary escape character: \+  no-useless-escape
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well from a quick glance I can see that you are escaping characters inside your regex character classes which probably don't need to be escaped.  So, try removing those `no-useless-escape`s:

```
let url = /^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w.-]+)+[\w\-._~:/?#[\]@!$&'()*+,;=.]+$/
```